# Dynamically adding FormGroup to FormArray

Tags: angular, dynamic, formarray

I'm looked at https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form and am trying to take it to the next level by using a FormArray that contains FormGroups but getting the following error when I click the submit button to look at the json:

'''
ERROR TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
--> starting at object with constructor 'Object'
|     property 'key' -> object with constructor 'FormControl'
|     property '_parent' -> object with constructor 'FormGroup'
--- property 'controls' closes the circle
'''

At a high level, I have a screen with an arbitrary number of sections.  My current code to convert the screen and sections to a FormGroup structure in my screen service:

```
// methods in screen service to convert model to FormGroup:

  toFormGroup(screen: ScreenVm){
    return this.fb.group({
      id: this.fb.control(screen.id),
      code: this.fb.control(screen.code),
      description: this.fb.control(screen.description),
      sortOrder: this.fb.control(screen.sortOrder),
      header: this.fb.control(screen.header),
      sections: this.fb.array([this.toSectionArray(screen.sections)])
    });
  }

  // array of sections
  private toSectionArray(sectionsArray: FragmentVm[]): FormArray{
    let sections = this.fb.array<FormGroup>([]);
    let sortedSections = sectionsArray.sort((a,b) => a.sortOrder - b.sortOrder);
    sortedSections.forEach((section, index) => {
      sections.push(this.toSectionGroup(section, index));
    });
    return sections;
  }

  // single section
  private toSectionGroup(sectionVm: FragmentVm, index: number): FormGroup{
    let section = this.fb.group({
      id: this.fb.control(sectionVm.id),
      code: this.fb.control(sectionVm.code),
      description: this.fb.control(sectionVm.sortOrder),
      header: this.toHeaderGroup(sectionVm.header)
    });

    return section;
  }

//screen-component.html
<div class="col-6">
  <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="screenForm">
  <dyn-header [header]="screenVm.header"></dyn-header>
    <div *ngFor="let section of screenVm.sections; let i=index" class="form-row">
      <app-fragment [section]="section" ></app-fragment>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row" style="padding-top: 15px">
      <button type="submit" [disabled]="!screenForm.valid">Save</button>
    </div>
  </form>
  <div *ngIf="payLoad" class="form-row">
    <strong>Saved the following values</strong>
    <br>
    {{payLoad}}
  </div>
</div>

// screen-component.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-screen',
  templateUrl: './screen.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./screen.component.css'],
  providers: [ScreenControlService]
})
export class ScreenComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() screenVm!: ScreenVm;  // TODO:: Need to change this to async observable
  screenForm!: FormGroup;
  payLoad = '';

  constructor(private scs: ScreenControlService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.screenForm = this.scs.toFormGroup(this.screenVm as ScreenVm);
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.payLoad = JSON.stringify(this.screenForm.getRawValue());
  }    
}

// block-component.html
<div>
  <dyn-header [header]="section.header"></dyn-header>
  <div *ngFor="let fieldGroup of section.fieldGroups" class="form-row">
    <app-block [fieldBlock]="fieldGroup"></app-block>
  </div>
</div>

//block-component.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-fragment',
  templateUrl: './fragment.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./fragment.component.css']
})
export class FragmentComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() section!: FragmentVm; 
  @Input() screenFormGroup!: FormGroup;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

Had a logic error building the sections FormArray that caused me to have an extra FormArray layer.  Since toSectionArray returns a form array, just needed to set sections equal to the return.  Changed from this:

```
sections: this.fb.array([this.toSectionArray(screen.sections)])
```

to this:

```
sections: this.toSectionArray(screen.sections)
```